# My wired Internet connection gets disconnected Ubuntu

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

OK, my wired ethernet port connection works great for as long as I am using it, but if I leave the computer and come back in an hour or so my connecting is still there, but there's no internet. This problem does not occur on my Windows PC when connected to the same ethernet port and it's not limited to the Ethernet port as I have the same problem with wireless when it's turned on (it's currently off).

Is there some power management that would turn off internet after a time? I'm really at a loss here.
I ran the following and will paste results.  Let me know if you need anything else.

```
sudo lshw -C network    

*-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlp7s0
   version: 00
   serial: 8c:a9:82:79:b9:92
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-59-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:28 memory:d2600000-d2601fff 

*-network 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:11:00.0
   logical name: enp17s0
   version: 06
   serial: 00:23:5a:d5:ad:49
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.0.200 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:24 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0c04000-d0c04fff memory:d0c00000-d0c03fff
```

Answer (score 0):

The r8169 driver that is currently being used for your ethernet is buggy.

Replace it with `r8168-dkms`, like so:

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
reboot
```

Comment: heynnema, thanks for the response. Will linux automatically update the driver to R8169 again, or will the R8168 install and remain?

Comment: r8168 will remain, and also get updated if a newer version is available. To vote/accept my answer, click on the grey checkmark, and the up arrow above the zero.

Comment: Great.  I'll try it and report back ASAP.  Thanks again for the response. I'll be sure to give you the credit if it works.

Comment: heynnema, I believe this solved the issue. I will try it tonight to verify that connection stays, but so far it remained longer than before. HOWEVER, my speed test is a fraction of what it used to be. Now that I know how to go to r8168 driver, how can I go back to r8169?

Comment: Also, since this ethernet adapter seems to be finicky in Linux, is there a good USB ethernet dongle for Linux you'd recommend?  I was thinking of the Amazon Basics 2.0 USB Ethernet dongle since I have a wired connection and it's only $10. I've spent more than 2 days on this dumb connection so $10 is money well spent if it works.

Comment: To go back to the r8169 driver, you just uninstall the r8168-dkms driver... but I don't think your speed issue is related. If you're going through a switch/hub, I'd power cycle it, along with the router/modem first and see if that improves things. I can't speak to USB to ethernet dongles.

Comment: @Michael status please?